# When is a holomorphic tangent bundle stable?

Tags: complex-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, ag.algebraic-geometry

Hello, I was thinking about the stability condition in terms of Mumford and I have a question:

> If $S$ is a compact Kahler surface (complex 2D), when is the holomorphic tangent bundle $T^{1,0}S$ stable?

When $S$ is Kahler-Einstein, $T^{1,0} S$ is stable by the Donaldson-Uhlenbeck-Yau theorem. But  Kahler-Einstein examples are rather restrictive as it requires the hermitian metric $h$ on $TS$ to be induced by the riemannian metric $g$. Would there be more examples other than Kahler-Einstein with stable holomorphic tangent bundles?

Thank you in advance.

=====

The following has been added to clarify some points.

**Appendix 1:** What I meant by Kahler-Einstein being "restrictive".

Hermitian-Yang-Mills connections or equivalently Hermite-Einstein metrics can be thought as a generalization of Kahler-Einstein metrics. $T^{1,0}S$ admits a Hermite-Einstein metric with the hermitian structure induced from $(S, J, g)$ when $S$ is a Kahler-Einstein. However, in principle $T^{1,0}S$ can admit a Hermite-Einstein metric even when $S$ is not Kahler-Einstein. In this case, the hermitian structure on $T^{1,0}S$ will be different from the one naturally induced from $(S, J, g)$.

**Appendix 2:** What I meant by stable bundle.

The stability condition introduced by Mumford is the following.

> A vector bundle $V$ is **stable** if for all coherent sub-sheaves $U$
> $$\frac{\deg (U)}{\mathrm{rank} (U)}<\frac{\deg (V)}{\mathrm{rank} (V)}.$$

Here the degree is computed using the Kahler form $\omega$ (polarization). By the Donaldson-Uhlenbeck-Yau theorem, on Kahler manifolds stability is equivalent to $V$ admitting a Hermitian-Yang-Mills connection. This theorem was later generalized by Li and Yau assuming stability to non-Kahler manifolds.

Comment: Maybe you can use the Yang-Mills interpretation of a Hermitian-Einstein connection.

Answer (score 6):

What do you mean by stable? usually stable is with respect to a polarization $H$. If $K_X$ is ample and you choose $H=K_X$ then we know by Aubin-Yau's theorem that there exists a Kahler-Einstein metric. Thus, in this case, the existence of such a metric is not restrictive.

If you choose any ample line bundle $H$, then Donaldson has proved that if a holomorphic vector bundle $E$ over a compact Kahler manifold $M$ admits an approximate $\omega$-Einstein-Hermitian structure if and only if $E$ is $H$-semistable, where $\omega$ is a Kahler form in the class of $H$.

You can find many details in Kobayashi's book *[Differential geometry of complex vector bundles](https://www.mathsoc.jp/assets/pdf/publications/pubmsj/Vol15.pdf)* (official Mathematical Society of Japan new pdf version).

Comment: Hello, thanks for the reply. Perhaps I should try to explain what I meant by Kahler-Einstein metrics being "restrictive". 

Hermitian-Yang-Mills connection (also known as Hermite-Einstein metrics) can be thought of a generalization of Kahler-Einstein metrics with Levi-Civita connection. In that sense, Kahler-Einstein metrics are trivial. 

Note that $T^{1,0}S$ can admit an Hermite-Einstein metric without $S$ being Kahler-Einstein. This can be achieved by using a different hermitian structure on $T^{1,0}S$ rather than the natural one coming from $(S,J,g,\omega)$.



Comment: Every line bundle $L$, on Kahler variety $X$ is stable in general